# How do I add an ID to an existing table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to cycle through the dom and add an ID attribute to an existing table element. Can't quite seem to get it working. Basicaly the code looks for a table that has a specific class, then adds an ID. More things will happen depending on the tables class but for the moment I'm stuck on adding the ID. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var chartTypeArray = [];
    var i = 0;    

    // cycle tables add id and store class
    $('table').each(function (i) {

        if ($(this).hasClass('bar')) {

            chartTypeArray.push('bar');    
            $(this).attr('ID', 'tableToChart' + i);

        } //end bar
        else if ($(this).hasClass('line')) {

            chartTypeArray.push('line');
            $(this).attr('ID', 'tableToChart' + i);

        } //end line

        else if ($(this).hasClass('area')) {

            chartTypeArray.push('area');
            $(this).attr('ID', 'tableToChart' + i);

        } //end area
        else if ($(this).hasClass('pie')) {

            chartTypeArray.push('pie');
            $(this).attr('ID', 'tableToChart' + i);

        } //end pie

        i++;

        console.log('Table ' + i + ' is a ' + $(this).attr('class') + ' chart');

    }); //end function
}); //end of document ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with lower case

```
$(this).attr('id', 'tableToChart' + i);
```

also you don't have to do

```
 var i = 0; //outside the each loop
            // and you don't need
     i++;   // inside the each loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Caramba, though that doesnt make any difference.

Comment: @woody problem must be somwhere else, adding id and reading id here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/rwmnryao/  if you need more help please create a fiddle with your markup

Comment: Caramba you evil genius you! It was the unnecessary increment i=0 and i++ causing the problem. Of course I didn’t need them, WHAT was I thinking? Thanks very much!

Comment: @woody nice one, glad it helped, happy coding!